# how to make uiscrollable find content-desc instead of text

Tags: java, android, appium, ui-automation

I'm trying to make a program to automatically respond to my emails within the gmail android app. I've gotten past the first initial steps but this is the next step :

when the program detects no unread emails, SCROLL until it finds more.

for this step, i am using the uiscrollable function :

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+A+"\").instance(0))");
Thread.sleep(2500);`
```

but instead of working at this point, the program scrolls through all the unread emails

is there anyway to make this uiscrollable function find the content-desc instead of finding the text?

[image]

thanks

Comment: I have added an answer please let me know if you find it useful or have any questions

Answer (score 0):

The main logic is:

1. Setup everything to connect with api (add libraries etc.)
2. Send request(query) for example with retrofit to that link `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/HerePutUserId/messages` with a parameter to get only unread messages as said the following link

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

[image]

3. Then just inflate it in recycler list as you want

You could modify following example as you need

```
public class MyClass {

    // ...


    /**
     * List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.
     *
     * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
     * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @param query String used to filter the Messages listed.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(Gmail service, String userId,
                                                          String query) throws IOException {
        ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).execute();

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query)
                        .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (Message message : messages) {
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
        }

        return messages;
    }

    /**
     * List all Messages of the user's mailbox with labelIds applied.
     *
     * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
     * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @param labelIds Only return Messages with these labelIds applied.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static List<Message> listMessagesWithLabels(Gmail service, String userId,
                                                       List<String> labelIds) throws IOException {
        ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId)
                .setLabelIds(labelIds).execute();

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setLabelIds(labelIds)
                        .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (Message message : messages) {
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
        }

        return messages;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Please let me know if you have any more questions